# How can you find a network printer's IP address on a Macintosh?

Tags: mac, printer, ip

What is the easiest way to find a network printer's IP address on a Mac? Since it is from a remote location, I can't print a configuration page. Under "Printer Setup" the URL listed is the network location (ie: //server/printer). However, that isn't as helpful as the static IP address. Anyone know how to view this on a Mac?

Comment: Were you hoping to print _directly_ to the printer, bypassing a print server? In that case, the only _reliable_ way to find the network IP address for a physical device is probably to print a configuration/settings page from the front panel controls.

Comment: As mentioned below, `[smb:]//server/printer` (or the Windows variant `\\server\printer`) indicates a central print server is hosting multiple devices/queues. You can confirm this with `smbutil view //server` from the macOS Terminal, or `net view \\server` from the Command Prompt in Windows. Try prepending `YOURNETWORKUSERNAME@` to the `server` part if your local username isn't the same as your network login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL is `\\server\printer`, try `nslookup server` (where `server` is the name from the URL) from a Terminal window.

Note, based on the URL style this printer doesn't have an IP of its own, rather it is hosted by a print server, and that print server has an IP. Since a print server can host multiple printers, you might need additional information beyond just the IP address (such as the printer name or printer queue) to actually send documents to it. This might be done for you if there's only one printer hosted, but that's implementation dependent.

Comment: I have the print queue name. However, since the server is a Windows server, the naming convention is different (with spaces). nslookup doesn't seem to parse those...

Comment: @ChrisHarris Try `nbmlookup "server name"` to see if samba is available on your machine.

Comment: @DarthAndroid, I believe that's `smbutil lookup "server name"` on modern macOS, but whether you actually get a response probably depends a lot on the parameters of your internal network, especially in a corporate environment. They may not route NetBIOS-over-TCP/IP at all.